# Criteria - searching against two columns concatenated

Tags: grails, hql, criteria, createcriteria

I am in need of a way to search against two concatenated columns with a Criteria in a grails project that I've been brought onto. The two columns make up a subject code for a University; a three-alpha-character code and a three-digit number. e.g. AAA123.

My research to date hasn't revealed any straight forward solutions because I have the following requirements:

- I need to use `Criteria` for the `PagedResultList` as the UI (Javascript/Ajax) works off the paged list and `totalCount`.
- I need to be able to use a wild card search, if the user searches for the alpha code (all subjects starting with 'AAA') or the specific subject ('AAA123').

e.g. `subj_code = '%AAA%'` or `crse_numb = '%123%'` or `subj_code || crse_numb = '%AAA123%'`

What I've found so far is that:

a) With Criteria, I cannot concatenate the columns (unless I've missed something)

b) I cannot use transients to join the columns

c) I cannot use `findAll` or `where` because they do not return `PagedResultList`.

If anyone knows of how to perform this using criteria or returning a PagedResultList, I'd be forever grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this `formula` property can help you because `formula` can participate in queries and it is `transient` by default.

Steps-

1. Create a formula property and concatenate your strings there.
2. use this formula property in your criteria query.

Use [this post](http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/create-transients-using-formula-in-grails/) for writing formula property.

Hope this help